# EndpointDispatcher and ClientRuntime missing

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, .net-5

Is there any alternative to accessing the ClientRuntime from EndpointDispatcher.

It seems that in .NET 5.0, using System.ServiceModel 4.8.1, EndpointDispatcher class is completely empty, only contains a single empty constructor.

We used to have some tests that would check that an `IEndpointBehavior` was properly added to the client using WCF.

```
var myEndpointBehavior = new MyEndpointBehavior();
var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("localhost"));
var dispatcher = new EndpointDispatcher(new EndpointAddress("http://localhost"), "", ""); // <--- Error because EndpointDispatcher class is totally empty
var clientRuntime = dispatcher.DispatchRuntime.CallbackClientRuntime; // <---- does not exist

clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Should().HaveCount(0);
myEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(serviceEndpoint, clientRuntime);
clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Should().HaveCount(1);
clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.First().Should().BeOfType<MyEndpointBehaviorMessageInspector>();
```

Is there any way to test this same behavior in .NET 5.0?

Comment: You may take a look at :[ASP.NET 5 - A Deep Dive into the ASP.NET 5 Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/march/asp-net-5-a-deep-dive-into-the-asp-net-5-runtime) and [EndpointDispatcher Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.endpointdispatcher.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceModel_Dispatcher_EndpointDispatcher__ctor_System_ServiceModel_EndpointAddress_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: The links you sent are both for .NET Framework, and as I mentioned above, this used to work properly in .NET Framework but it changed completely for .NET Core and .NET5.0. So those resources no longer apply

Answer (score 0):

Since `ClientRuntime`'s constructors were hidden away and I couldn't really access it any way, I ended up using `Activator` to access the private/internal constructor of `ClientRuntime`. It is not an elegant solution but it allows us to test the behavior.

```
var myEndpointBehavior = new MyEndpointBehavior();
var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("localhost"));
var clientRuntime = (ClientRuntime) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClientRuntime), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, new[] { serviceEndpoint.Contract.Name, serviceEndpoint.Contract.Namespace }, null, null);

clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Should().HaveCount(0);
myEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(serviceEndpoint, clientRuntime);
clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Should().HaveCount(1);
clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.First().Should().BeOfType<MyEndpointBehaviorMessageInspector>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The method has changed FROM/TO:**

FROM:

```
 SchemaValidationMessageInspector inspector =
               new SchemaValidationMessageInspector(schemaSet,
                          validateRequest, validateReply, true);
            clientRuntime.**MessageInspectors**.Add(inspector);
```

TO:

```
SchemaValidationMessageInspector inspector =
           new SchemaValidationMessageInspector(schemaSet,
                      validateRequest, validateReply, true);
        clientRuntime.**ClientMessageInspectors**.Add(inspector);
```